# Enumerating 5 distinct elements into 3 subsets

Tags: combinatorics

What is manual way of enumerations of 5 items into 3 different subsets.

Enumeration of any number of items mechanically into subsets of size 1 is just each element on it's own.

Enumerating into subsets of size 2 is just picking one of the elements from original set and then picking another elements.

enumerating into subsets of size n, where n is less than or equal to size of original set can be done recursively.

But cant seem to find a similar mechanical way to enumerate all the possible 3 subsets of 5 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To divide five items into three non-empty subsets, you could divide them $3-1-1$ or $2-2-1$. There are ${5 \choose 3} = 10$ possible ways to handle the first case, and ${5 \choose 4}{3 \choose 1} = 15$ to handle the second case. Considering the numbers 1 through 5, the first case would contain:

$$\{1, 2, 3\}, \{4\}, \{5\}$$
$$\{1, 2, 4\}, \{3\}, \{5\}$$
$$\{1, 2, 5\}, \{3\}, \{4\}$$
$$\{1, 3, 4\}, \{2\}, \{5\}$$
$$\ldots$$
$$\{3, 4, 5\}, \{1\}, \{2\}$$

The second case would then contain:

$$\{1, 2\}, \{3, 4\}, \{5\}$$
$$\{1, 2\}, \{3, 5\}, \{4\}$$
$$\{1, 2\}, \{4, 5\}, \{3\}$$
$$\{1, 3\}, \{2, 4\}, \{5\}$$
$$\ldots$$
$$\{2, 5\}, \{3, 4\}, \{1\}$$